# Getting wpf gridid

Tags: wpf, grid, wpf-positioning

If in my wpf application there are multiple grids and a dragable user control.Can anyone suggest code that could return different grid id every time the control is dragged over different grids.

Comment: Doesn't your grid have a name?

Comment: Well it does not matter gridid or grid name. Can i get that as return value when i drag and drop it over that grid?

Comment: @peer: he wants the element under the mouse, how does naming grids helps in any way?

Comment: I didn't get the question right, I thought he did not know which property he could use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Mouse.DirectlyOver` then go up the visual tree to find the first `Grid` up the tree.

`Mouse.DirectlyOver` returns the `IInputElement` that is under the mouse at the time you check the property.

You can walk up the visual tree using a method described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686128/677014)

Edit: I found the SO question about [visual tree walking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls) i was thinking about. (much better than the first link IMHO).

Comment: +1 for finding me the link I looked at a long time ago about navigating WPF's visual tree. I've actually made some changes to that code and re-posted it on my blog, but I couldn't find the source of it to give them credit for it.

Comment: @Rachel I googled the comments i had in my code, and took the first SO result =)