# GridViewColumn.Width binding and double-click to autosize column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Binding column width like this

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
            ... more columns
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The problem: when double clicking column header line (to autosize column) no `Width` setter is triggered, which means binding source is not updated after such column width changing. Normal column resizing works without problems.

Suggestions?

I don't want to [prevent double-click autosizing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686010/1997232), only to fix an issue.

Comment: What is `Width` in this context? Make sure your DataContext is set, check the output window for clues.

Comment: @MikeEason, everything is working (normal column resizing in both directions - by code or by dragging column header line) until you double-click.

Comment: Ok, does the width actually change? I mean, you can double click, but if the width of the column doesn't change, then the bound property will not be updated. Try putting a breakpoint in the **set** part of your property (assuming it's just a CLR property) to see if it hits.

Comment: It does changes. I noticed issue by what the width set by double click is not memorized and if I restart application - previous width is set. And breakpoint in setter was the first thing I did. It's not triggered when you double-click and width visually changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [double click handler source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GridViewColumnHeader.cs,1a1040a5a185a238), it looks like the `Width` property should be updated. Perhaps something is going wrong in the binding? You might want to [make your binding verbose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx) and see what prints in the output window.

That issue aside, you may not get the behavior you desire by binding to the `Width` property. As you can tell from the [double click handler](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GridViewColumnHeader.cs,1a1040a5a185a238), it gets set to `NaN` to make the column automatically resize. This means that even if your property setter gets called, it is going to get `NaN` passed to it. You could bind to `ActualWidth` using a `OneWayToSource` binding mode, unless you actually need the binding to be `TwoWay` for other reasons.

Comment: Interesting observations, thanks. Unfortunately I need `TwoWay` binding to restore column width from code (when application is started).

Comment: *Verbose binding* is really great, thanks. Your `NaN` observations helped, there is indeed *System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'n. def.' (type 'Double')* in Output window, which cause problems with binding.. to `int`, lol.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've solved the question doing this:

1.
I have a property "_gridView" which is the GridView object representing the view of a ListView whose name is "_listView".

```
<ListView x:Name="_listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="_gridView">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Whatever"/>
        </GridView >
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

2.
I haved added this other piece of code to updated the width of the columns of the GridView. This is based on [this .NET reference of GridViewColumnHeader](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/1a1040a5a185a238.html).

```
private void UpdateWidths()
{
    foreach (var column in this._gridView.Columns)
    {
        column.Width = column.ActualWidth;
        column.Width = Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

3.
And in the constructor of the WPF window, I've inserted this other code to execute the update of the widths each time the "ItemsSource" of "_listView" changes.:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor
        .FromProperty(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ListView))
        .AddValueChanged(_listView, (s, e) => {
            UpdateWidths();
    });
}
```

4.
Therefore, each time I change the "ItemsSource" property of the object "_listView" all the columns are updated.

```
_listView.ItemsSource = __New value__
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to delete my question, but perhaps it will be usefull (I doubt) to someone else doing same mistake.

Problem was with `Width` type. I used `int` and it seems to works flawlessly. But it doesn't work with double-click resizing for whatever reasons.

To fix: use `double Width {get; set;}` to bind to, not `int`.